# Render different controller for the same url for different user rails ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Is it possible to render different controller and template for the same url for different type of user rails ruby.

I want to show designers and admin users a different page and general users a different page for the same url

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:** Redirect different kinds of users to different controllers and templates for the same URL. Note that this will involve an extra round-trip to the browser.

**Option 2:** Simply have two different templates for the designers and admins for the same action of the same controller. Of course, the action will have to use conditional statements to setup instance variables correctly.

**Option 3:** Based on how different the views need to be and how you have architected your application so far, you can also go for a [presenter](http://railscasts.com/episodes/287-presenters-from-scratch). With some clever attribute naming, this can easily turn out to be the simplest solution to maintain.

> I don't want to re write/duplicate code. how can i use the code from the other controller and also render a different template – C J

You didn't mention that you already have that action somewhere. You are then looking for writing helpers which you can call from both your controllers - the existing one and the one which responds to this URL.

Comment: i don't want to re write/duplicate code. how can i use the code from  the other controller and also render a different template

Comment: Did it answer your question? If you need more specific input, you should provide some code as well.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** No standard way to do it, might be possible but certainly not advisable.

Routes and constraints work on the *request*, which would be the same for designers and admin users if it pointed to the same URL. So the standard rails way of defining routes wouldn't allow you to specify different constraints here, unless you'd have your roles in a header value, which would be a very bad thing to do.

Having said that, you could use authorization gems like [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) (not available on Rails 4 yet) which let you do things like

```
<% if can? :update, @article %>
  <%= link_to "Edit", edit_article_path(@article) %>
<% end %>
```

in the view and

```
def show
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  authorize! :read, @article
end
```

in the controller to specify who is permitted to perform an action. If you had two different urls `/designers/foo` and `/admin/foo` they should point to different controllers but could easily share code through standard Ruby modules.

```
require 'foo_actions'

module Designers
  class FooController
    include FooActions
  end
end
```

That way you had clean URLs pointing to separate controllers and proper views but no duplicate code.